# returning from void function throws exception.

Tags: java, android

I have written a function that throws CustomException1, CustomException2.

```
void myfunction() throws CustomException1, CustomException2
{
  .. At some point in time, i am return from this function.
  if ( some condition fails)  return ;

}
```

**Problem:**

But the problem is that it return from the function, but at the same time
this throws the CustomException1.

How can i make sure to not throw CustomException1 while returning the function.

The interesting part is if reorder the Exceptions names like

```
  void myfunction() throws CustomException2, CustomException1,
```

then the while i return from the function, CustomException2 is thrown.

Comment: Does `void` return any value?

Comment: No, it does not, i just use return statement based on certain conditions.

Comment: please post the whole code.

Comment: The function should not throw an exception while returning. You cannot return and throw an Exception at the same time. We need your code to help you.

Comment: @Satya void returning 'any value'? void indicates the method returns nothing, this is one of the basics of Java

Comment: Sorry, but this question makes no sense at all.  Your function cannot both `return` and throw an exception (unless the `return` is in a `finally` block).  It may be throwing an exception from some other point in the code.  A stack trace would help us see where.  Basically, though, you need to post a complete example.

Comment: @JörnBuitink nothing is returned, it's void.

Comment: @Stultuske I meant it the way ajb described it.

Comment: Specifying `throws CustomException1, CustomException2` just means that method *can* throw those checked exceptions, it doesn't mean that it will/must. Why do you think it does throw something? Do you see a stack trace? If so, show it.

Comment: @Stultuske, I knew that asking it as ?

Answer (score 1):

just handle it in try-catch block

```
    try
    {
        if(some_condition_fails)
            return; 
    }
    catch(CustomException1 e) 
    {
        //here handle exception
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the question is why the exception is throw while i return, rather than how to catch it.

Comment: Then reedit the question because now it is **How can i make sure to not throw CustomException1 while returning the function.**. Why -1?

Comment: Sure, but i do not know why -1 for this. :)

Answer (score 1):

No. This merely means that

> during the process of running the method (not function), these
>   Exceptions may be thrown, and will not be handled within the method,
>   but have to be handled by the method that calls this method.

So:

```
public void divide(int i, int y){
  int x = i/y;
}
```

This is bad coding (not looking at the names). As far as you know, both i and y might be 0.

So, in case:

```
divide(5, 0);
```

An exception will be thrown. Now, let's say you want to handle it with your own type of Exception, or with a personal error message:

```
public void divide(int i, int y) throws MyException{
  if ( y == 0 ){
    throw new MyException("You can't divide by 0");
  }
  return i/y;
}
```

Here, it might throw an Exception that is propagated to the calling method, but only if y is 0.

so, either the call would be:

```
try{
  int x = getRandomValue();
  int y = getRandomValue();
  divide(x, y);
}
catch(MyException me){
  log("It seems y was 0");
  me.printStackTrace();
}
```

or, you don't catch it here, but propagate the Exception further.

Of course, you can avoid this, by having a try-catch block in the method itself.